# How to display data inserted from texteditor like tinymc on android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can we display data or text that has been inserted through a website using a text editor like tinymc? I have one bold sentence and ordered list in my website. Below is the example

In my website

**I am Header**

1. First
2. Second
3. Third

In My Android Application

I am header First Second Third

I am wondering that is it possible to display like in website in android or not. Is their any way or it is not possible in android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Html.fromHtml()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler)) to have a similar kind of formatting in android textviews.

For example: To make it work on android API < 24

```
    myTextView.setText(
               Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br>
                   <ol>
                   <li>Coffee</li>
                   <li>Tea</li>
                   <li>Milk</li>
                   </ol>"));
```

For >= 24 use:

```
myTextView.setText(
                   Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br>
                       <ol>
                       <li>Coffee</li>
                       <li>Tea</li>
                       <li>Milk</li>
                       </ol>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```